# Estrutura do Commit

Tags: git, data, struct, commit

Gostaria de saber se tem como alterar estrutura de um commit,
no caso antes de ele ser feito uma estrutura pré determinada, exemplo:

```
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME = '$name(Previamente registrado)'
GIT_AUTHOR_DATE = '$date(data do sistema)'
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE = '$date(data do sistema)'
```

A partir disso ao  fazer um commit automaticamente alteraria a hora para do sistema onde está o repositório e não do sistema de origem.
Seria possível pré-determinar essas coisas através de um pre-commit?

Comment: Você quer alterar o horário do commit no servidor ou pode ser na máquina do desenvolvedor mesmo?

Answer (score 3):

O Git, por padrão, salva no commit o timestamp Unix (quantidade de segundos deste 1970) e o timezone (especificamente, o *offset*) no qual o usuário está no momento.

[Por exemplo](https://saebamini.com/Git-commit-with-UTC-timestamp-ignore-local-timezone/), um commit neste exato momento faria com que o Git salvasse o commit com as seguinte informações:

```
commit c00c61e48a5s69db5ee4976h825b521ha5bx9f5d
Author: Seu Nome <seu-nome@email.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 14 09:22:00 2018 -0200 # Horário local e offset. Estou no horário de versão brasileiro, caso contrário seria -0300

Mensagem de commit aqui
```

O que você quer é usar o horário local e *offset* do local do repositório e não da máquina do usuário. Assim, digamos que o repositório do servidor está em UTC (*offset* 0000).

Você pode até especificar a data manualmente no commit, utilizando o formato ISO 8601:

```
git commit --date=2018-12-14T01:00:00+0000
```

Mas não é viável fazer isto a cada commit. A melhor maneira é fazer isto de forma automática. Assim, você pode obter esta data atual usando o comando `date` no formato ISO 8601 em UTC e passar para o comando de commit do git, desta maneira:

```
git commit --date="$(date --utc +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z)"
```

Para não precisar aplicar este comando toda vez, você **pode criar uma alias** para este comando todo de commit e utilizar sempre ele:

```
git config --global alias.utccommit '!git commit --date="$(date --utc +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z)"'
```

E para commitar:

```
git utccommit -m "Mensagem de commit com data em UTC, igual do repositório"
```

Agora, se ideia for realmente usar o Hook do Git, lendo a [documentação](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) eu não encontrei um jeito fácil de fazer. Entendo que seria possível usar o hook de `post-commit`, capturar o último commit local (o commit que acabou de ser feito) e alterar a data, usando algum script de hook [como este](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9832486/2387977).